# jQuery performance | Avoid repeating code

Tags: jquery, performance

**Note**

I think I can explain this without a jsfiddle. I'll avoid to show the whole code because there is too much HTML with lots of classes that I would have to adapt to the example.

Also, excuse my bad English. I hope you understand me. Im learning.

**The point is**

I have some modules that overlays my interface when the user activates the respective button. I want all the modules do the same animation when opening.

**How is it now?**

Now I am repeating again and again the same code (below), but pointing to each module and its respective button... I'm a newb in terms of javascript but I know this is anti-performance... I feel like I can do it cleaner.

**My doubt**

Is there a way to make a function or something with this code to allow it to work for all the modules I want, without repeating it again and again?

```
$('#btn-moduleX, #close-moduleX').on('click', function(){
    $( "#btn-moduleX" ).toggleClass('layout-color-subBase');
    $( "#overlay-moduleX" ).toggleClass('overlay--hidden');

    var currentOpacity = $('.fx-appear-soft').css('opacity');
    $( ".fx-appear-soft" ).animate({
        'opacity': 1 - currentOpacity
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Sure. Use a class. `<button class="someclass">` and attach a click to all of these buttons at the same time : `$("button.someclass").click(...` Then inside use `$(this).toggleClass(...`

Comment: If the code is identical each time, just attached to different elements, then write it as a jQuery extension/plugin/widget. Google "creating jQueryUI widets" and "extending jQuery".

Comment: You can try  posting this here too: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JeremyThille  then, how I select the module to open? How I attach each button to each module?

Comment: I would add some data to the button, like `<button class="someclass" data-module="module1">`. Then you access the data using `moduleName = $(this).data('module')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets imagine your button was looking like this:

```
<a id="btn-moduleX" href="#">Button</a>
```

What we do is removing the id and adding the class name that will be the same for all the buttons and the `data-module` attribute, where we do write the related module name.

```
<a class="jsCloseModule" href="#" data-module="moduleX">Button</a>
```

new JavaScript code:

```
$('.jsCloseModule').on('click', function(){
    var moduleName = $(this).data('module');
    $( "#btn-" + moduleName ).toggleClass('layout-color-subBase');
    $( "#overlay-" + moduleName ).toggleClass('overlay--hidden');

    var currentOpacity = $('.fx-appear-soft').css('opacity');
    $( ".fx-appear-soft" ).animate({
        'opacity': 1 - currentOpacity
    }, 300);
});
```

This is just an example. Your application could be optimized much more, all that id's like `"#btn-" + moduleName` could be changed to classes too.

Comment: now I realize that when I open 2 modules, both they receive opacity 0 :( how could I make the opacity animation work in each module too?

Comment: You could use selectors like this: `var moduleElement = $('#' + moduleName); var someModuleElement = moduleElement.find('.fx-appear-soft'); someModuleElement.animate(.animate({
        'opacity': 1 - currentOpacity
    }, 300)`